# Can someone please help with this Riemann integration problem?

Tags: real-analysis

Calculate the $L(P, f)$ and $U(P, f)$ (lower and upper sums, respectively) for the function $f:[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$.  defined as:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\sqrt{1-x^2}& \mbox{if}\,\, x \,\, \text{is rational, }\\
1-x, &\mbox{if}\,\,x \,\,\text{is irrational.}
\end{cases}$$
and let $P=\{0, 1/n, 2/n, \dots, n/n\}$.

Before asking here, I did try to solve this myself. I'm stuck on how to get the infimum and supremum on each subinterval of $[0, 1]$. Also, if the function is integrable on the interval, what is its value?

Comment: Notice that $\sqrt{1-x^2}\ge 1-x$ for $x\in [0,1]$ (square on both sides, simplify, then you're left with $x^2\le x$ which is true for $x\in[0,1]$).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For all $x\in [0,1]$, $\sqrt{1-x^2}\ge 1-x$

Comment: Can you please explain how to prove this inequality?

Comment: For $x\in [0,1]$, $\sqrt{1-x^2}\ge 1-x \Leftrightarrow 1-x^2\ge (1-x)^2 \Leftrightarrow 2x\ge 2x^2 \Leftrightarrow x(1-x)\ge 0$.  This last always holds in $[0,1]$ since both factors are nonnegative.

Comment: @Bakhatiar Those are very simple functions which you should be able to graph.  One describes a circle and the other a line.

Comment: @paw88789 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We have that $L(P,f)=\sum_{i=1}^n(\frac{i}{n}-\frac{i-1}{n})inf _{t \in [\frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}{n}] } f(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n(\frac{1}{n})(1-\frac{i}{n})=\frac{1}{n}(n-\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{n})=$=$1-\frac{1}{n}(\frac{n(n+1)}{2n})=\frac{1}{2}(1-\frac{1}{n})$;

$U(P,f)=\sum_{i=1}^n(\frac{i}{n}-\frac{i-1}{n})sup _{t \in [\frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}{n}] } f(t)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(\frac{j+1}{n}-\frac{j}{n})sup _{t \in [\frac{j}{n},\frac{j+1}{n}] } f(t)=$ $=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\sqrt{1-(\frac{j}{n})^2}$.